# JPA fetching 3 records inside entity collection OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I faced a problem when i want to retrieve records with OneToMany relation in the entity, what i want is to fetch specific records for the entity and all the relations inside it for a Collection? how can i do it using JPA Query?

```
...
public class JsPost implements Serializable, Comparable<JsPost> {
        ...
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "postId")
        private Collection<JsComment> jsCommentCollection;
        ...
}
```

and in `JsPostDAO` for `fetch(...)` method

```
    public List<JsPost> fetch(int min, int max) {
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM JsPost p order by p.postDateCreated DESC");
            query.setFirstResult(min);
            query.setMaxResults(max);
            return query.getResultList();
    }
```

After i call fetch method all `JsComments` for `JsPost` retrieved? how can i set max results for the `Collection<JsComment>`? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> After i call fetch method all JsComments for JsPost retrieved?

No. The association is lazy by default, so no JsComment instance is loaded by the database by this query. It's only when calling a method on `somePost.getJsCommentCollection()` that the comments of the post will be retrieved.

> how can i set max results for the Collection?

The question is irrelevant, since the comments are not fetched.

Side note: your naming is awful. Why not name these entities `Post` and `Comment`. And naming the collection `comments`, instead of `jsCommentCollection`? Isn't it more redable to have `post.getComments()` than `jsPost.getJsCommentCollection()`?

Comment: thanks for answer :), no no the netbeans IDE itself generated variables from database and named as jsCommentCollection and Js is shortcut for the project name. for me i don't do this for the realistic project but to understand the JPA technology, umm i understand from your answer when i call fetch method the comments will not loadded because by default fetching type is LAZY.